# groovy / Java: Intercept method call from outside library

Tags: java, groovy, metaprogramming, interceptor, metaclass

I have a simple groovy script in which I call a method named `cron(String cronExpression)` from `ItemTriggerContext`, like:

```
job('george') {
    triggers {
        cron('5 4 4 4 4')
    }
}
```

I want to allow the cron method to be called only if some of my validations of the input String pass.

`if(myValidationsOfCronExpr are ok) {
    call the cron method with said parameter
} 
else {
    return null
}`

This is why I need to intercept all calls to the `cron()` method from my project.

Already tried http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-intercept-methods-with.html and https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-use-the-intercept-cache-invoke-design-pattern-groovy.cfm but they seem applicable only on your own classes.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: is it jenkins pipeline?

Comment: No, standard JobDSL plugin to generate a simple job.

Comment: so it's declarative language not runtime. probably you need to [extend DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Extending-the-DSL)...

Comment: I think you should describe your use case. Are you the one writing the DSL? If so you can just do cron(validateCron('5 4 4 4 4')) and define a validateCron(String input) { do validation here... }. Another alternative might be a completely separate plugin, nothing to do with Job DSL, that validates the cron string for any job.

Comment: That's the problem, it's an open source project that anyone in my company can contribute to so I can't force ppl to use the validateCron() method, that's why I have to do it even if they submit their code as cron('5 4 4 4 4'). A separate Jenkins plugin just for this? Huh...

Comment: I guess the only solution is to have a wrapper over the cron method and rely on code review to use the wrapper instead of the default cron.